# Protractor E2E Testing Error: Cannot find module 'selenium-webdriver'

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor

```
Error: Cannot find module 'selenium-webdriver'
```

I have installed *protractor* and *selenium-webdriver* globally using `npm install -g protractor webdriver-manager update`

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');


describe('modes of failure', function() {
  it('should fail to find a non-existent element', function() {
    browser.get('index.html#/form');

    // Run this statement before the line which fails. If protractor is run
    // with the debugger (protractor debug debugging/conf.js), the test
    // will pause after loading the webpage but before trying to find the
    // element.
    browser.debugger();

    // This element doesn't exist, so this fails.
    var nonExistant = element(by.binding('nopenopenope')).getText();
  });

  it('should fail to use protractor on a non-Angular site', function() {
    browser.get('http://www.google.com');
  }, 20000);

  it('should fail an assertion', function() {
    browser.get('index.html#/form');

    var greeting = element(by.binding('{{greeting}}'));

    expect(greeting.getText()).toEqual('This is not what it equals');
  });
});
```

Comment: Why do you want to require the webriver this way?

Comment: Could you try to run the example with this command line please ?

`protractor node_modules/protractor/example/conf.js`

Answer (score 8):

You need to install the node module:

```
npm i selenium-webdriver --save-dev
```

Comment: You save my day!

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to remove the `var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');` ?

You shouldn't need it, you can access it in your test via `browser`

> `browser` this is the a wrapper around an instance of webdriver. Used for navigation and page-wide information.

(quoted from [Getting started - Protractor docs](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md))

If you've already installed the Selenium standalone server using `webdriver-manager update`, and started it with `webdriver-manager start`, all you have to do is to run your tests using

```
protractor path/to/your/protractor-conf.js
```

Answer (score 1):

When you type:

```
webdriver-manager
```

Into the terminal, the these helpful options appear:

```
webdriver-manager
Usage: webdriver-manager <command>
Commands:
  update: install or update selected binaries
  start: start up the selenium server
  status: list the current available drivers
```

Have you tried `update`, `start`, or `status`?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the standalone option:

```
$ webdriver-manager start --standalone
```